# Custom parsing string

Tags: c#, string, split, string-parsing

When parsing FTX (free text) string, I need to split it using `+` as a delimiter, but only when it's not preceded by escape character (say, `?`).
So this string `nika ?+ marry = love+sandra ?+ alex = love` should be parsed to two strings: `nika + marry = love` and `sandra + alex = love`.
Using `String.Split('+')` is obviously not enough. Can I achieve it somehow?

One way, it seems to me, is to replace occurrences of `?+` with some unique character (or a succession of characters), say, `@#@`, split using "+" as a delimiter and then replace `@#@` back to `+`, but that's unreliable and wrong in any possible way I can think of.

`?` is used as an escape character only in combination with either `:` or `+`, in any other case it's viewed as a regular character.

Comment: You can try to use regular expressions for this.

Comment: could you bee more specific?

Comment: what happed if   `"?+"` exists in word/sentence ?   then your logic of replace `"?+"` not work ..

Comment: @shree.pat18 It becomes complex if `?` can be escape with `??`, so that `??+` doesn't split.

Comment: @xanatos Yes, true. OP needs to give some idea of the possible variations on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An horrible regular expression to split it:

```
string str = "nika ?+ marry = love??+sandra ???+ alex = love";
string[] splitted = Regex.Split(str, @"(?<=(?:^|[^?])(?:\?\?)*)\+");
```

It splits on a + (`\+`) that is preceded by the beginning of the string (`^`) or a non-`?` character (`[^?]`) plus an even number of `?` (`(?:\?\?)*`). There is a liberal use of the `(?:)` (non-capturing groups) because `Regex.Split` does funny things if there are multiple capturing groups.

**Note that I'm not doing the unescape!** So in the end `?+` remains `?+`.

Comment: What if string ends with `?+` ? I don't now we should return nothing or an empty string. Yours return nothing, mine returns empty string. also +1 for horrible regex!

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "nika ?+ marry = love+sandra ?+ alex = love";
        string[] result = Regex.Split(s, "\\?{0}\\+", RegexOptions.Multiline);                  
        s = String.Join("\n", result);      
        Regex rgx = new Regex("\\?\\n");
        s = rgx.Replace(s, "+");
        result = Regex.Split(s, "\\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);                         
        foreach (string match in result)
        {
             Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
        }   
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
'nika + marry = love'
'sandra + alex = love'
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/HkcQUw